# Unable to move 0's to the end of list properly Python

Tags: python

So the goal here is to move all 0's to the end of the array but I stumble across a problem from these small lines of code.

When I use the input I get the desired output like so:

```
Input: [0,1,0,3,12]
Output: [1,3,12,0,0]
```

However, whenever I use this input:

```
[0,0,1]
```

I get this output:

```
[0,1,0]
```

When I want the output:

```
[1,0,0]
```

I have no idea why I thought I implemented this properly:

```
class Solution:
def moveZeroes(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    for counter in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[counter] == 0:
            nums.pop(counter) #Remove the 0
            nums.append(0) #Add to end. 
            counter-=1 #Check same index just incase adjacent 0
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: there is an easier way to this:
`x = [1,5,6,0,4]` and than sort your list: `x.sort(reverse = True)`

Comment: @J.A.Cado That's not the same thing. It'll sort all values, not just shunt the zeroes to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop is not a equivalent to a `while` loop with increment. Your last line `counter-=1` doesn't achieve anything: after you decrement `counter`, it immediately takes the next value in the range. (To be clear, if you were at iteration `counter = 2` for example, no matter what value you leave `counter` at at the end of this iteration, it will be reassigned to `3` at the next iteration.)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't even bother with a manual for loop...

```
def move_zeroes(nums):
    nums[:] = [n for n in nums if n != 0] + [0] * nums.count(0)

x = [0,1,0,3,12]
move_zeroes(x)
print(x)
```

outputs

```
[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `[n for n in nums if n]` is shorter :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure, if you believe everything in the list is numbers ;)

Comment: I didn't even come close to this solution. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
counter-=1 #Check same index just incase adjacent 0
```

Does not decrease the indexing for the **following** indices.

Try this instead:

```
class Solution:
    def moveZeroes(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        zeros_found = 0
        for counter in range(len(nums)):
            idx = counter - zeros_found
            if nums[idx] == 0:
                nums.pop(idx) #Remove the 0
                nums.append(0) #Add to end. 
                zeros_found += 1 #Account for offset
```

You could also do this more functionally:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
# ...
def moveZeroes(self, nums):
    none_zeroes = list(filter(None, nums))
    zeros = list(filterfalse(None, nums))
    return none_zeros + zeros
```

Or if you don't want to create lists for no reason:

```
from itertools import filterfalse, chain
# ...
def moveZeroes(self, nums):
    none_zeroes = filter(None, nums)
    zeros = filterfalse(None, nums)
    return list(chain(none_zeros, zeros))
```

These rely on two implicit facts:

1. `bool(0)` is `False`, and `bool(x)` when `x != 0` is `True`
2. `filter(None, list)` filters list by item's `bool` value, so no 0s (and opposite for filterfalse)